# ASP.NET Core razor asp-fallback to the fallback

Tags: .net, razor-pages, cdn

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.5/jquery.validate.min.js"
        integrity="sha512-rstIgDs0xPgmG6RX1Aba4KV5cWJbAMcvRCVmglpam9SoHZiUCyQVDdH2LPlxoHtrv17XWblE/V/PP+Tr04hbtA=="
        crossorigin="anonymous"
        referrerpolicy="no-referrer"
        asp-fallback-src="~/Identity/lib/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"
        asp-fallback-test="window.jQuery && window.jQuery.validator">
</script>
```

As you can see in the above markup, if jQuery fails, it falls back to a local source. What I would like to see is, a fall-back-src-primary and a fall-back-src-secondary. Such that, if there was an issue with one CDN, it tries another CDN. Then if that one has an issue, it falls back to local, or a tertiary CDN, or a chain of CDNs

Does anything like this exist?